# Checkbox decision in ajax & php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This is my first post guys, please forgive me for any glaring posting errors.
I'm attempting to create a checkbox in an html page but I would like to retrieve data from my .php page. At this point in my code it doesn't matter whether the box is checked or not, it shows the same answer (that it is) - any suggestions ??

HTML code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction()
{
var xmlHttp;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    try
      {
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    catch (e)
      {
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
      return false;
      }
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
      {
      //alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
      document.getElementById("DisplayBox").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
      }
    }
  // start the query string
  var QueryString = "IceCream_Coating.php?";
  QueryString = QueryString + "checked=" + document.getElementById("checked").value;
  //alert(QueryString);
  xmlHttp.open("GET", QueryString, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }

</script></head>

<body>
<p>Is the box Checked</p>
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="checked" id="checked" value="yesORno"></p>
   <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Decision" onclick="ajaxFunction();"/>
  </p>
</form>
  <p>
    <div id="DisplayBox">
    </div>
  </p>
</body>
```

PHP code

```
<?php

$value = $_GET['checked'];

if (isset($value)) {
    echo "Yes the box is checked.";
} else {
    echo "No, the box is not checked.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Try changing your php `if` syntax to: `if(isset($_GET['checked'])) {` etc....

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: `document.getElementById("checked").value` will give you the value for the checkbox. It doesn't check if it is checked or not. The value of that element will still be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the checkbox is checked or not. Currently, you're just fetching the value that is set on the element, regardless if it's state.

Try this:

```
var QueryString = "IceCream_Coating.php?";

if (document.getElementById("checked").checked) {
    // Only add the value if it is checked
    QueryString += "checked=" + document.getElementById("checked").value;
}
```

We also need to change the PHP code:

```
<?php
// We need to check if the parameter is set before trying to use it
$value = isset($_GET['checked']) ? $_GET['checked'] : null;

if ($value) {
    echo "Yes the box is checked.";
} else {
    echo "No, the box is not checked.";
}

?>
```

Comment: What would happen if i ever made an ajax call with `{'checked':false}`, Magnus? :)

Comment: I just updated the code. Then it would say, "not.checked". If you want to say that it is checked in those cases, then just change the if statement to: `if (is_null($value))`. That would say that it is checked, as long as the value won't validate as null.